# Riemann surfaces and homogeneous spaces

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I would like to understand the connection between Riemann surfaces and homogeneous spaces, in the case of the upper half plane.

I am reading a book in which they define a linear element in a Riemann surface as a pair made of a point and a direction (I think of a it as a tangent vector at that point). $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})=G$ is the set of the conformal transformations (action by fractional linear transformations) of the upper half plane.

An homogeneous space is a space endowed with a continuous action, i.e. a representation of topological spaces. It can be identified with $\Gamma \backslash G$ where $\Gamma$ is a closed subgroup (namely, the stabilizer of a point).

They then interpret the homogeneous space as the space of linear elements, and say these linear elements are more interesting than the Riemann surface itself, since it is an homogeneous space. But wasn't it already the case of $\Gamma \backslash G$? Is there a subtlety I am missing here?

Comment: It's very hard to intepret an indirect description of what the book is saying on this point.

Comment: I don't understand what "wasn't it already the case of $\Gamma\backslash G$" means.

Comment: Also $1/z$ doesn't preserve the upper half plane, so the description of how $G$ acts on $\mathcal H$ needs to be improved beyond just fractional linear transformations. The orientation preserving conformal automorphisms are $PSL_2(\Bbb R)$, and $\bar{z}^{-1}$ is an orientation-reversing one. Does adjoining the involution $\bar{z}^{-1}$ yield an isomorphic copy of $PGL_2(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: The tangent bundle of the upper half-plane is a *principal* homogeneous space for $PSL_2(\Bbb R)$, unlike the upper half plane itself. Could that be what they're talking about?

Comment: @runway44 I'm sorry for being unclear in the question, I mostly want to understand what adding the directions to the points add to the structure we get, I always had in mind homogeneous spaces as set of points modulo a group of motions, without thinking about directions. It could well be a better way to see my question, even though they do not mention "principal" when they define or talk about homogeneous space in this context. Could you elaborate this difference?

Comment: It's not a difference, it's a special case. If a group $G$ acts transitively on a set $\Omega$ (i.e. $\Omega$ is a homogeneous $G$-space) with stabilizer $H$, then $\Omega\cong G/H$ are equivalent as $G$-sets. If stabilizers are trivial, then $\Omega\cong G$. Then $\Omega$ is called a *principal* homogeneous space. Equivalently, the action is *regular*: not only does there exist a group element taking any set element to any other set element, but there is a unique such group element. Sometimes called a "$G$-torsor."

Comment: If you pick a particular element of $\Omega$ (a principal homogeneous space) to be an "origin" (aka a "distinguished point") then that creates a one-to-one correspondence between group elements and set elements, and the group's action on the set matches the group's regular action on itself by multiplication.